# Gettng this error when trying to pass pointer by referene

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to make a delete node function in a BST and I need to pass a pointer by reference so I can change the pointer, but I keep getting this error:

'void Tree::deletNode(T,Node *&)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'Node *' to 'Node *&'

There are 2 of these errors and they happen in deletNode when calling itself recursively.

The program runs when I do not have an & but it doesn't work as expected.

These are my 2 functions that are supposed to delete a node in the BST.
the root ptr of the tree is called root and Node is the node type.
Also, the deletNode function is called which calls the makedelete. but the user calls deletNode

```
    void deletNode(T num, Node<T> *& nodeptr)
{
    if (num < nodeptr->getData())
        deletNode(num, nodeptr->getLeft());
    else if (num > nodeptr->getData())
        deletNode(num, nodeptr->getRight());
    else
    {
        cout << "called makedelete on " << nodeptr << "which has " << nodeptr->getData() << endl;
        makedelete(nodeptr);
    }
}

void makedelete(Node<T> *& nodeptr)
{
    Node<T> * tempnode;

    if (nodeptr == nullptr)
        cout << "error..." << endl;
    else if (nodeptr->getRight() == nullptr)
    {
        tempnode = nodeptr;
        nodeptr = nodeptr->getLeft();
        delete tempnode;
    }
    else if (nodeptr->getLeft() == nullptr)
    {
        tempnode = nodeptr;
        nodeptr = nodeptr->getRight();
        delete tempnode;
    }
    else //has 2 kids
    {
        tempnode = nodeptr->getRight(); ///move 1 node to right

        while (tempnode->getLeft()) // go to end of left
        {
            tempnode = tempnode->getLeft();
        }

        tempnode->setLeft(nodeptr->getLeft());
        tempnode = nodeptr;
        nodeptr = nodeptr->getRight();
        delete tempnode;

    }
}
```

};

Here is the Node class:

```
template <typename T>
class Node
{
    T data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
public:
    T getData() { return data; }
    Node<T>* getLeft() { return left; }
    Node<T>* getRight() { return right; }
    void setData(T t) { data = t; }
    void setLeft(Node<T>* pLeft) { left = pLeft; }
    void setRight(Node<T>* pRight) { right = pRight; }
};
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is something wrong with the post?

Comment: Yes.  You don't show the definition Node - its data members and functions.

Comment: OK  I added the Node Class

Comment: fman. Read the instructions you were given.

Comment: You should also proof-read things and use the *preview* of your post *before* you actually make the posts and/or future edits.

Comment: I don''t understand what the problem is with my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Node<T>* getLeft() { return left; }
```

This returns by value. So the returned `Node<T>*` is a temporary. Note that because you return `left`'s *value* and not a reference to `left` or a pointer to `left`, you cannot modify `left` by calling `getLeft`.

```
void deletNode(T num, Node<T> *& nodeptr)
```

This takes a non-const reference to a `Node<T>*`.

```
    deletNode(num, nodeptr->getLeft());
```

Here, you try to call `deletNode` on the temporary returned by `getLeft`. But you cannot bind a non-const reference to a temporary. You cannot modify `left` through the return of `getLeft`, because it returns neither a reference nor a pointer.

The fix depends on what you really want to do, but it's definitely not to try to pass a temporary to a function that takes a non-const reference. Are you expecting the call to `deletNode` to modify `nodeptr->left`? If so, `getLeft` needs to return a reference.

Comment: Another issue is that `left` is a dangling pointer after all this (not sure if OP is aware that `left` will not be set to null). The whole design of `deletNode` is junk

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. !!!That error message seemed like the error was something else though.

Comment: Regarding dangling pointer, the makedelete function has a delete in it that will delete the pointer

Answer (score 0):

What happens is the nodeptr->getLeft() or nodeptr->getRight() will result in a rvalue and you are trying to hold the reference of a rvalue which is wrong. of it in the deletNode..

Before you can pass it to deletNode, do this

```
Node<int>* tmp = node->getLeft();
deletNode(tmp);
```

You can hold a reference to rvalue in c++11, to do so, change the signature of deletNode to

```
void deletNode(Node<T> *&& nodeptr)
```

Comment: Surely you mean `deleteNode(tmp)`?

Comment: Your second suggestion will mean the function no longer works for lvalues though

Comment: Thank you! This is another way to solve the problem. Unfortunatly I can't upvote yet